# Shift right and Add in one command

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am learning assembly language for ARM Cortex and I have the following problem:

> Write one line of assembly instruction for the following calculation:
>   Apply Arithmetic Shift Right on the content of R2, then add the
>   contents of R1 and R2 and store the result in R0.

I understand the Arithmetic Shift Right as:

`ASR R0, R2, #9`

And to do an add is simply:

`ADD R0, R1, R2`

But i am unsure how to combine these into one command. 
So far I have come up with the following from an example i saw that looked as if they were doing two commands on one line in a similar way:

`ASR R0, R2, #9, [ADD R1, R2]`

I know this is probably wrong, so can anyone explain to me how this should be done?

Comment: Use `add` with a shifted input operand.  It doesn't work the other way.  http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html

Comment: @PeterCordes, something like: `ADD R0, R1, R2, ASR #9`?

Comment: That's almost exactly like one of the examples on the page I linked, so yes, I think that's valid syntax.  You should check that it assembles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are on the right track now.

```
add rd, rn, rm, asr #n
```